# How to ensure value is not replaced in array to set Cookie in AEM / cq5

Tags: javascript, arrays, cookies, aem

I am using AEM and each time a user visits a specific type of page, the page path needs to be added to its own cookie (max 3 pages allowed on the recently visited page). I tried using request.getCookies(), and adding the page links to an array, then join the array to a string and then add this to a single cookie. This did not always work as the cookie value was not always fetched correctly, but then after a few refreshes of the page it would display fine.

Another requirement is that the array needs to be from most recently visited (pos 0) to oldest, hence the unshift.

I have since made use of document.cookie to set up 3 separate cookies to keep each page link, but the splice in the following code is causing the first item in the array to always be replaced leaving the array always with 1 value only and I am unsure why or how as the following code seems correct:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
$(function () {

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var paths = [];
        var cookie0 = getCookie("cookie0");
        if (cookie0 != "")
            paths.push(cookie0);
        var cookie1 = getCookie("cookie1");
        if (cookie1 != "")
            paths.push(cookie1);
        var cookie2 = getCookie("cookie2");
        if (cookie2 != "")
            paths.push(cookie2);

        //syntax for cookie: path1 + separator + path2 + separator + path3
        var separator = '&';
        var newpath = document.getElementById("currentPagePath").value; //the fund page we're viewing and want to add to the cookie

        //first check if the page is under a specific type
        if(newpath.indexOf("type") != -1)  //if it is under a certain page type, then add to the cookie
        {        
            //check if the newpath exists already in the cookie positions, can only have max 3 but don't want duplicates listed of the same page 
            var foundPos = paths.indexOf(newpath);

            //will need to remove from pos if found or if length is 3
            if(foundPos >-1 || paths.length >=3 )
            {
                paths.splice(foundPos, 1);
            }

            paths.unshift(newpath);

            //finally add to the cookie
            setCookie(paths, 30);
        }
    });

    //Set cookie
    var setCookie = function (paths, expiryDays) {
        for(var i=0;i<paths.length;i++)
        {
            var expirydate = new Date();
            expirydate.setTime(expirydate.getTime() + (expiryDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "expires=" + expirydate.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = "cookie"+i + "=" + paths[i] + ";" + expires + ";path=/";

        }
    }

    //Get cookie 
    var getCookie = function (cookieName) {
        var name = cookieName + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');

        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }      
}); });
```

Comment: try jquery.cookie library hope it will help, i am also using AEM seems that jquery behave differently in AEM.

Comment: btw the three functions at the top are redundant. they are all various ways of invoking a callback function on DOM ready. you may get rid of two of those. the middle one is the shortest format when working with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The best library I have used for cookies is [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) it is lightweight and extremely simple to use.

> Pure jQuery does not ship with cookie manipulation plugin, you can use js-cookie OR a jquery cookie plugin. In this answer, I will use js-cookie

include the js-cookie in your clientlib then you can do the following:

> Note that code below works according to the requirements you gave, you may have to adjust if you want to remove duplicates, or if there are other code dependencies.

```
var HISTORY = 'urlHistory';
$(function() {
  var currentPage = $("#currentPagePath").val(); // get the path value to store
  var urls = Cookies.getJSON(HISTORY); // get the current url history cookie
  console.log('before: ', urls); // logging url history before adding new url
  if (!urls && currentPage) { // this case is for fist time when cookie is empty
    Cookies.set(HISTORY, [currentPage]);
  } else if ($.isArray(urls)) { // here, cookie has some urls
    var full = urls.length >= 3; // check if the url list is full, 3 is max
    if (full) {
      urls.pop(); // it is full, remove the last one
    }
    urls.unshift(currentPage); // add the new url to the beginning
    Cookies.set(HISTORY, urls); // save the urls
  }
  console.log('after: ', urls); // log urls after
});
```

if you want to test it, you can do so in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/